# Есть что нибудь такое же на C# как в php

Tags: c#

Есть что нибудь такое же на C# как в php http://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.variable-functions.php . Пример 1

Comment: Приведенный вами пример смахивает на рефлексию. Она в C# есть. Но вообще то, что описывается по этой  ссылке - ужасное говнокодство. Если в подобных трюках есть необходимость, то это значит только то, что код написан криво

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такое можно сделать при помощи reflection. Но C# — во много раз более мощный язык, в котором такие низкоуровневые трюки обычно не нужны. Если вам нужно такое, скорее всего вы делаете что-то неправильно. Расскажите, какую именно задачу вы решаете.

Например, пример 1 на C# обычно кодируется так (без reflection):

```
void f(string s) { Console.WriteLine("f({0}) called", s); }
void g(string s) { Console.WriteLine("g({0}) called", s); }

Action<string> a;
a = f;
a("hello"); // "f(hello) called"

a = g;
a("hello"); // "g(hello) called"
```

Comment: надо же, мой комментарий оказался практически аналогичен вашему ответу)

Comment: @DreamChild: И правда :)

Comment: Просто стало интересно